# Getting URL content in chunks with callback function

Tags: perl

How can I check if the callback function called for each chunk of the response content is called with the last chunk of data or if more data is about to come?

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( ... );

my $request = $ua->get($url, ':content_cb' => sub
{
  my ($d, $r, $p) = @_;
  
  # need to know if this is the last chunk of data

});
```

Comment: Just put your code for the last chunk after `})`

Comment: @ikegami - I know about that option, but... There is no way to check it inside the callback function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see in the source, the callback isn't called back on eof or error.

But there's no need for that. That code can be placed after `get` returns.

If you want a common sub to handle data, eof and error, feel free to call it in both the callback and after `get` returns.

```perl
my $response = $ua->get( $url,
   ':content_cb' => \&cb,
);

cb( "", $response, undef )
```

Answer (score 3):

Can find out when the response was completed via the `response_done` [handler](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#response_done-=%3E-sub-%7B-my($response,-$ua,-$handler)-=-@_;-...-%7D)

> **response_done => sub { my($response, $ua, $handler) = @_; ... }**
> The handler is called after the response has been fully received, but before any redirect handling is attempted. The handler can be used to extract information or modify the response.

This is added to the user-agent object as

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->add_handler(response_done => sub { ... });
```

By the time this fires there is no data in `$response` if `:content_cb` callback is used, since that removes data. But we get to know about the completion and can set flags (not seen in `:content_cb` callback though) or directly run/trigger other processing.

There is also a `response_data` handler, called on each chunk, which can be used to collect data as it comes (instead of `:content_cb`)

```
$mech->add_handler ( 'response_data' => sub {
    my ($response, $ua, $handler, $data) = @_;  
    ...
    #$response->content(undef);  # remove data from response as it is received?
    return 1;  # so we keep being called
});
```

I also find the `response_header` handler to be useful sometimes (to detect start of data in streams for instance).

Comment: `:content_cb` is implemented as a `response_data` handler internally. `:content_file` is implemented as a `response_data` and a `response_done` handler internally.

Comment: @ikegami OK, good to know, thank you.  But `response_done` can also be used independently, merely to get to know when the response completed, what is very directly related to the question.  That's all I am saying.  (I mention `response_data` by the way, as it is related, once I suggest a handler.)